# Rabbitmq high availability with Celery

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

We have two node master/slave rabbitmq cluster setup. And trying to test the rabbitmq high availability feature. If master goes down, oldest slave is promoted to the master and should start executing from the current job/task.

We observed that current job is getting executed by the newly promoted master,but after completing the job, consumer (i.e. Celery worker) tries to connect to original master by sending an acknowledgment instead of sending that to newly promoted master. Due to this reason current job is getting executed twice.

Any help..? Assuming that consumer's acknowledgment should be respected by the rabbitmq master and then should not start the current job once again.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you should have a software/hardware load balancer fronting the RabbitMQ cluster. The [RabbitMQ Clustering Guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html) has an explanation and a good outside resource for explaining why this is the correct approach is [here](http://blog.flux7.com/blogs/tutorials/how-to-creating-highly-available-message-queues-using-rabbitmq).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any alternative other than load balancer.

Comment: There are many advantages for using a load balancer with RabbitMQ.  In your case since you would setup a FQDN that represents the cluster.  The load balancer will route the message/connection to any of the servers within the cluster.  What I have done in the past is to have the load balancer recognize that the node is down and remove it from the load balancer (and the cluster in your case).  Then, after a period of time and figuring out what's wrong with the node, the node is brought back into the load balancer and cluster.

Comment: Also, are you using HA and mirrored queues?  It seems after re-looking at your question it seems that celery may be holding a connection open to the RabbitMQ server.  That does not seem possible if you have shutdown the server to create a new "Master."  Also, is the consumer queue set to No-Ack?  That may be your problem as well.